# chartjs question: Is it possible to have body/footer text that has different fontsize inside tooltip?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Question about chartjs 3.x

I was able to customize the tooltip by setting property values of `plugins.tooltip` and `plugins.tooltip.callbacks`.

my sample code

```
tooltip: {
                callbacks: {
                    footer: function (context) {
                        "69%"
                        }
                    },
                   
                    label: function (context) {
                       return "TEST"
                        }
                    },
                },
                backgroundColor: "#FFF",
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "black",
                titleFont: {
                    size: 14,
                    weight: "light",
                },
                footerFont: {
                    size: 20,
                    weight: "bold",
                },
                titleColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 1)",
                bodyColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 1)",
                footerColor: "black",
                displayColors: false,
                titleAlign: "center",
                bodyAlign: "center",
                footerAlign: "center",
                padding: 8,
            },
```

what I want to achieve is to have a smaller font size for `%` like the pic below

[image]

I read through doc, but I could not find the way..
Is there any way to achieve this except creating external html tooltip?

Comment: Have a look to the tooltip doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips how to create an HTML tooltip

Comment: yes, I know that I can do this using html tooltip, but I was wondering if it's doable without using it. @user2057925

Comment: I did some research but I don't think there's any way other than using html tooltip.  thanks for the comment :) @user2057925

Comment: I think whoever needs HTML toolip is using a custom tooltip implementation, starting from the sample provided by the doc.